# Is 创业者 the best translation of entrepreneur as somebody who is trying to run a startup?

Tags: translation

I have looked for that word. The most common translation seems to be 企业家. However, I think 企业家 can be confused with big businessman. I want to say 我是企业家, but I'm not a big businessman. I'm just trying to run a startup, so I think I should say 我是一个创业者. Am I right?

Comment: alternative suggestion:初创着 cf。初创者们的野心时代
 http://chuansong.me/n/1304223
bkrs：初创的企业 a newly established enterprise 初创公司，初创工业 also see jukuu：10.  The startup, Aviva Bioscicences, is developing miniaturized " lab on a chip" systems for use in drug research and disease diagnosis.
 初创的腾隆生物科技公司正在开发用于药物研究和疾病诊断的微型"芯片实验室"系统。also see MDBG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

企業家 (T) or 企业家 (S) is the correct translation for "entrepreneur"
it doesn't indicate the size of  the business that person is running, ,

For that, we have 大企業家 (T) or 大企业家 (S) meaning large profile entrepreneur)，and 小企業家 (T) or 小企业家 (S) meaning small profile entrepreneur.

For a start up business owner, the term is 新進企業家 (T) or 新进​​企业家 (S) meaning start up entrepreneur

創業 (T) or 创业 (S) means "to start a business"

創業者 (T) or 创业者 (S) means " one who starts his or her own business"

---

T: Traditional Chinese

S: Simplified Chinese

Comment: I forgot about this question. Thank you for your very complete answer! :)

Comment: what about  创业者 by the way. Does it mean something?

Comment: 創業者 is 创业者 in traditional characters, I don't know how to input simplified characters.

Comment: So 創業者 (T) or 创业者 (S)  are OK, but  新進企業家 (T) or 新进​​企业家 (S) are more clear. Right? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 创业者 is the correct answer.

Comment: Why do you think somebody has vote you down? Maybe because it is a short answer? Strange.

Comment: The problem is the lack of evidence to support the claim: something is not true just because a random person on the Internet says it's true.